# VueRouter: component não renderiza ao chamar o path da rota

Tags: vue.js

Estou tentando carregar o component Cadastro ao clicar em Cadastro na barra de navegação mas, apesar de passar o path para a url, o component não é carregado em App.vue. Estou usando o Vue CLI:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em main.js fiz o import e registro do VueRouter:

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import {routes} from './routes.js'

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: routes
}) 

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Criei o arquivo routes.js:

```
import Cadastro from './components/Cadastro.vue'

export const routes = [
    {path: './cadastro', component: Cadastro}
]
```

No component Navbar.vue eu passo o router-link para chamar o path do component cadastro:

```
  <li class="nav-item">
    <router-link class="nav-link" to="./cadastro">Cadastro</router-link>
  </li>
```

Em App.vue eu passo o router-view para renderizar o component Cadastro:

```
    <template >
    <div id="app">
        <meu-menu :rotas='routes'></meu-menu>
        <router-view></router-view>
      </div>
    </template>

import Menu from './components/shared/Navbar.vue'
import {routes} from './routes.js'

export default {

  components: {
    'meu-menu': Menu
  },

  data () {
    return {
      routes: routes
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você criou esta rota, me parece que há apenas 1 (uma) rota. Desse modo não há em que navegar.

```js
import Cadastro from './components/Cadastro.vue'

export const routes = [
    {path: './cadastro', component: Cadastro}
]
```

Contudo, considerando que você tenha criado todas as rotas, de modo que seu app tenha mais de uma rota. Tente utilizar outros modos para navegar tais como:

```html
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" @click="$router.push('cadastro')">Cadastro</a>
  </li>
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).